# How to use WP_Query to get nested values of an object?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have searched a lot online with no luck on searching nested values

lets say i have a users array

```
[
{
 id: 0,
 billing: {
  phone: "999999"
 }
},
{
 id: 1,
 billing: {
  phone: "777777"
 }
}
]
```

I want to use WP_Query to filter by phone number is it possible to do that ? and how ?

```
function get_customers(WP_REST_Request $request) {
        $param = $request['phone'];

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'customer',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'key'     => 'billing.phone',
                'value'   => $param,
                'compare' => '='
            )
        );

        $customers = new WP_Query($args);
        return $customers->posts;
    }

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('rc/v1', 'customers/(?P<phone>\d+)', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_customers'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Please share full code.

Comment: actually there is no code i am just searching for documentation that helps me filter users with phone number (nested object) all i can see is comparing direct properties

Comment: so you mean you will pass phone number and matched value want to return a single object?

Comment: exactly mate do you know any way to achieve this ?

Comment: are you sure key name is `billing.phone`?

Comment: phone is nested object of billing, my problem is that I am not sure if this is the correct syntax to search for nested objects and probably is not the correct way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233612/discussion-between-raffi-and-bhautik).

Comment: please find in the database where your phone number is stored and if it's stored in post meta then what is the meta key name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `meta_query` syntax is wrong it's should be inside one more array [check here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)  and If your post meta key is `'billing.phone'` then the below code will work fine.

```
function get_customers( WP_REST_Request $request ) {

    $param = $request['phone'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'customer',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'billing.phone',
                'value'   => $param,
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );

    $customers = new WP_Query($args);
    return $customers->posts;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('rc/v1', 'customers/(?P<phone>\d+)', [
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_customers'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: I am sorry I think there is some misunderstanding, I want the exact thing but using WP_Query arguments

Comment: I think your question is not clear. why do you want to use `WP_Query `?

Comment: apologies mate, I am creating a custom REST API endpoint to search users with their phone number, let's say we have post type called users i want to query users by their phone number

Comment: where you store phone numbers?

Comment: phone number is nested in user object -> billing -> phone

Comment: no, it's now how this works. you should give some context, code you trying, how you save this information to the user, etc.

Comment: please do not add an explanation code in the comment. add in your question.